# Watin IE becomes visible when using a LINQ where

Tags: c#, linq, console-application, where-clause, watin

So basically i'm trying to find all hidden IE windows, this should be an easy task for LINQ. So i tried a simple where:

```
var Instances = IE.InternetExplorers().Where(x => x.Visible == false);
```

but when i call the `InternetExplorers()` it makes all the instances visible and gets no results.
So i tried to a different where:

```
var Instances = IE.InternetExplorers().Where(x => x.Title != "");
```

This also makes all instances visible, but obviously gets all the open IE windows.

So is there a way to select all instances that are not visible without making them visible, or am i doing somthing wrong?

Comment: Your call to `InternetExplorers()` must set all instances to visible.

Comment: Yes, this is true, so is there an alternative way to get all the instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, i looked into the watin [source](http://autowebagent.googlecode.com/svn-history/r18/WatiN-2.0.10.928-net-2.0/source/src/Core/IE.cs) and found that the `InternetExplorers()` method just returns `new IECollection(true);` so i looked at the `IECollection` [constructor](http://autowebagent.googlecode.com/svn-history/r18/WatiN-2.0.10.928-net-2.0/source/src/Core/IECollection.cs) and found that `WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.ShellWindows2()` returns all the browsers.

So in the end i did this:

```
var allBrowsers = new WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.ShellWindows2().Where(x => x.Visible == false);

foreach (SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2 internetExplorer in allBrowsers)
{
    //do somthing.
}
```